# Exclude in get_pages() based on meta field

Tags: query, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using `get_pages()` in order to get all the posts from a custom post type hierarchically for creating a custom "next/previous" navigation.

I use it like this:

```
    $sibling_list = get_pages(array(
        'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
        'sort_order' => 'asc',
        'post_type' => 'guideline',
    ));
```

I want to exclude posts from this query based on if the post has a certain value to an ACF field. The field is named "no-visit" and has a boolean value. I want to exclude all posts that have "no-visit" set to `true`.

Is this possible to do with get_pages()?

Answer (score 0):

You can using get_posts().

```
$pages_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'parent' => 0,
  'post_type' => 'guideline',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_key'  => 'no-visit',
  'meta_value' => 'true'
);
$pages = get_posts($pages_args);
```

```
$pages_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'parent' => 0,
  'post_type' => 'guideline',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'no-visit',
            'value' => 'true',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
$pages = get_posts($pages_args);
```

meta_compare Possible values are '!=', '>', '>=', '<', or '<='. Default value is '='

Comment: Would that exclude though? I want all posts with "no-visit" set to true to not be included. Also, when using get_posts(), for some reason the order of the posts are wrong. get_pages() is giving me the correct order with the query in my original post. Not sure why, but could it be that get_pages() uses some kind of hierarchy that get_posts() doesn't? The posts are nested in some occasions, so a child's next post could be a grand child.

Comment: you can use meta_compare.

Comment: for sort: 'sort_order' => 'asc'.